# What is the best way to handle a collection of non-entity classes in JHipster?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jhipster

We currently are working on a third-party REST API integration. Many of those responses' JSON data have JSON arrays. The simplest case is an array of String data. To save the data in the same data structure in the relational database, data conversion is needed. One such data conversion is the following.

public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List, String> {

```
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> strings) {
    if (strings == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return String.join(",", strings);
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joinedStrings) {
    if (joinedStrings == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return Arrays.asList(joinedStrings.split(","));
  }
}

@Entity
public class Foo {

  @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
  private List<String> strings;
  ...
}
```

It won't make any sense to convert such collection data to a many-to-one relationship and have the list of String as a list of an entity class.

To my knowledge, JHipster doesn't have a way of handling a collection of non-entity out of the box. What would be the best way to handle a collection of non-entity classes in JHipster?

**Update:**

Based on GaeL's suggestion, I ask Bard how to work out the JSON data approach. Here are three drafts it provided:

> Here are the steps on how to save JSON data to PostgreSQL with Spring Data JPA:

> 1. Create a PostgreSQL database and a table with a JSON column.
>    Create a Spring Boot project and add the following dependencies to your pom.xml file: ...

> 2. Create a Java entity class that represents the data you want to store in the database. The entity class should have a property of type JSONB.
> 3. Create a Spring Data repository interface that extends the CrudRepository interface. The repository interface should have methods to save, update, delete, and find the JSON data.
> 4. Create a Spring Boot application class and configure the database connection.
> 5. In the main method of the application class, create an instance of the repository interface and save the JSON data.
>    Here is an example of how to save JSON data to PostgreSQL with Spring Data JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @JSONB
  private String data;

  public Person() {
  }

  public Person(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}

Person person = new Person("{\"name\": \"John Doe\", \"age\": 30}");
personRepository.save(person);
```

> The JSON data will be saved to the database in the data column of the Person table. You can then query the database to retrieve the JSON data.

The second approach is the following:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Convert(converter = JsonToMapConverter.class)
  private Map<String, String> info;
  ...
}

public class JsonToMapConverter implements 
AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> attribute) {
    return JSON.toJSONString(attribute);
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    return JSON.parseObject(dbData, Map.class);
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer("John Doe", new HashMap<>(Map.of("age", "30", "country", "USA")));
customerRepository.save(customer);

Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(1L).get();
Map<String, String> info = customer.getInfo();
System.out.println(info);
```

The third approach is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private UserInfo userInfo;

  public User() {
  }

  public User(UserInfo userInfo) {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
  }
  ...
}

User user = new User(new UserInfo("John Doe", "john.doe@example.com"));

// Save the user to the database.
userRepository.save(user);
```

And for an JSON array, the only approach is the same as the previous one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private List<String> phoneNumbers;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private List<UserInfo> userInfo;

  public User() {
  }

  public User(List<String> phoneNumbers, List<UserInfo> userInfo) {
    this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
  }
 ...
}

    User user = new User(Arrays.asList(new UserInfo("John Doe", "john.doe@example.com"), new UserInfo("Jane Doe", "jane.doe@example.com")), Arrays.asList("123-456-7890", "987-654-3210"));

    userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: if you use Postgresql as your database, have you considered using a JSON column?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks very much for your hint. The app does use PostgreSQL. I learn various approaches for a single piece of JSON data (see the update. If the first approach indeed works, I can define the JSON attribute as the String data type in its JDL. For a JSON array, how to define the data list in its JDL file? Although there is a lot of customization of JHipster generated code, I would like to keep a JDL file as a  blueprint for long-term maintenance purposes. Our customization approach is to have extensions of repositories and services with as few changes on entity classes as possible.